# How to import gradle ear artifact to Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, war, ear

I have the following situation:

I am trying to write a little project in Java which should produce a single EAR file which contains a single WAR. There might be some JARs in the future, but it is not important now.

I need to use gradle for build automation and Intellij for developing. I have some problems with synchronization between those tools.

I have prepared a gradle project ‘ear-app’ with the ‘ear’ plugin applied. It depends on a second project ‘web’ which is war. It works well with gradle wrapper. ‘build’ task builds ‘ear’ file.

Unfortunately Intellij has not recognized the

‘ear’ artifact. In “Project Structure”, there is only web application artifact which comes from ‘web’ project.

Is it possible to make Intellij be able to recreate ‘ear’ artifact?

I do not keep intellij files in my repo, so I need a solution which bases on gradle configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this was asked [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747987/intellij-automatic-creation-of-ear-artifact-from-gradle-project) in the meantime, and got this response from [ɐuıɥɔɐɯ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695271/%C9%90u%C4%B1%C9%A5%C9%94%C9%90%C9%AF):

> Seems automatic artifact configuration is [not implemented yet](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84122) in IDEA