# IntelliJ: Automatic creation of ear artifact from gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm having a gradle project with the following structure:

```
Root project 'project-gradle'
 +--- Project 'ejb'
 +--- Project 'ear'
 \--- Project 'war'
```

The build is working perfectly on command line, I'm using the ear plugin and it is built correctly.

Unfortunately when I import the project to IntelliJ (or open it with the gradle-created intelliJ files), the only available artifact is war. But I need the ear.
Any way to get this without manually defining the ear-Artifact inside IntelliJ?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Look for the `Gradle projects` tool window (at the right) and do a `Refresh All Gradle projects`

Answer (score 3):

Seems automatic artifact configuration is not implemented [yet](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84122) in IDEA